# Memory game board creation, javascript

Tags: javascript

Im trying to make a memory game in javascript, but im having problems with creating the board + adding an event handler(click) to the images that are going in the table data. heres the code snippet:

```
 var board = document.getElementById("board");
 var img = document.createElement("img");
 var NUM_ROWS = 6;
 var NUM_COLS = 6;
 for (row = 0; row < NUM_ROWS; row++) {
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    for (col = 0; col < NUM_COLS; col++) {
        var td = document.createElement("td");
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        tr.appendChild(td);
        img.src = 'images/image0.png';
        tr.appendChild(img);
    }
    board.appendChild(tr);
 }
```

Comment: And the exact problems you're having are...?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the code I wrote for https://github.com/jslegers/findpairs

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. One way that gives you a lot of flexibility is to build up a string version of the image element that has all the features that you need and insert it into your table cell element by setting td.innerHTML as follows:

```
function myclick(row,col) {
  // handle the click here
}

var board = document.getElementById("board");
var NUM_ROWS = 6;
var NUM_COLS = 6;
for (var row = 0; row < NUM_ROWS; row++) {
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  for (col = 0; col < NUM_COLS; col++) {
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    var src = "images/image0.png";
    var img = '<img src="'+src+'" onclick="myclick('+row+','+col+');">';
    td.innerHTML = img;
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }
  board.appendChild(tr);
}
```

In this case, the img element is created with the onclick function built in and will provide the row and column of the click to your click handling function.